# SQL concatenated names get lost in rest of result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing zip, name and nb. If an entry has the same number (nb) as another one I wan to concatenate their names. So far it's working:

[Here is SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efbef6/1/0) with the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `blubb` (
  `zip` varchar(51) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(51) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nb` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('1', 'aa', 1);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('2', 'bb', 2);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('3', 'cc', 3);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('4', 'dd', 2);

SELECT 
    zip,
    name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY zip SEPARATOR '|') AS names
FROM blubb
GROUP BY nb
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+
| zip | name  | names   |
+-----------------------+
| 1   | aa    | aa      |
| 2   | bb    | bb|dd   |
| 3   | cc    | cc      |
+-----------------------+
```

But what I need is this:

```
+-----------------------+
| zip | name  | names   |
+-----------------------+
| 1   | aa    | aa      |
| 2   | bb    | bb|dd   |
| 3   | cc    | cc      |
| 4   | dd    | dd|bb   |
+-----------------------+
```

So if a number (nb) exists more then one time I don't want to lose it (which happend in my result). I want to select it and concatenate the names in alphabetic order. The name of the row itself should always be at first place in `names` followed by the other names in alphatbetic order.

Is this possible? How do I need to change my Query? I tried change the GROUP BY but nothing came closer to what I have.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: thanks for the advice @jarlh

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your ordering requirement `dd|bb`. It may help you, when clarifying, to add an example that has three items in the name `qq|rr|ss`. I think specifying this completely may prove difficult.

Comment: @O.Jones thanks for checking back. Well I tried to explain in the question which got updated 4 hours ago. As my query is the `GROUP_CONCAT` should order by zip which is wrong (but would work in the given example). But I would like the name of row first and the rest in alphabetical order. So if there would be rows with the name of `qq`, `rr` and `ss` the the result of names should be 1. `qq|rr|ss`  2. `rr|qq|ss` 3. `ss|qq|rr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [O. Jones answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46712784/2008111) it was easy to do some string manipulation to get the desired output at the end. This query is was I was looking for, maybe it's helpful to someone else:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18f8a4/1/0)

```
SELECT
    a.zip,
    a.name,
    REPLACE(
        CONCAT( a.name, '|', b.names ),
        CONCAT('|', a.name),
        ''
    ) AS names
FROM blubb a
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            nb,
            GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name ASC SEPARATOR '|') AS names
        FROM blubb
        GROUP BY nb
        ) b ON a.nb = b.nb
 ORDER BY a.zip
```

and the table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE `blubb` (
  `zip` varchar(51) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(51) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nb` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('1', 'aa', 1);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('2', 'bb', 2);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('3', 'cc', 3);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('4', 'dd', 2);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('5', 'ab', 2);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('5', 'cb', 2);
INSERT INTO blubb (zip, name, nb) VALUES ('6', 'ca', 2);
```

[here is SQL Fiddle with alphabetical order on the resulting names](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d4b149/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT q.zip, q.name,
       ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(w.name ORDER BY w.zip SEPARATOR '|')
         FROM blubb AS w
         WHERE w.nb = q.nb
         ORDER BY w.name <> q.name, w.name ) AS names
FROM blubb AS q
ORDER BY q.name ASC
```

### Edit

Added ordering, that the actual value would be the first. However, if there are multiple rows with the same value, all of them would go to the beginning of the list...

Comment: That looks better, but zip 4 has the wrong order of names

Comment: What order should it be, EG if there are 15 of them?

Comment: The name concat order should be the `zip` order so for zip 4 i need `dd|bb`

Answer (score 1):

You've been bitten by MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).  A standard server would reject your query.

What you need is a subquery to get the list of names for each value of nb. Like so.

```
      SELECT nb,
             GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY zip SEPARATOR '|') AS names
        FROM blubb
       GROUP BY nb
```

Then you join that to your detail table.  Like so. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efbef6/9/0)

```
SELECT a.zip, a.name, b.names
  FROM blubb a
  JOIN (
          SELECT nb,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY zip SEPARATOR '|') AS names
            FROM blubb
           GROUP BY nb
       ) b ON a.nb = b.nb
 ORDER BY a.zip
```

Comment: Thaks for the explanation! Is there a way to get the order of names also correct? See zip 4 is `bb|dd` but I need `dd|bb`

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I've already upvoted your answer. Now I could solve the requirement with your help (answer is somewhere on this page). You might want to have a look at it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
select b.zip, b.name, g.names
from blubb b 
inner join (SELECT 
    nb,
    GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY zip SEPARATOR '|') AS names
FROM blubb
GROUP BY nb) g on b.nb = g.nb
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: I thought that would not be important, if that is then you could achieve the same result adding some string manipulation tricks to result to get the row value in front.